# ToString does not work

Tags: tostring

Why toString doesn´t work in my code? The output should be all elements that are in the idChild[].

Error:

> child[Ljava.lang.String;@15db9742

```
public String[] onePointCrossover(int father, int mother) {

    String linha1 = individualID.get(father);       
    idFather = linha1.split(" ");
    String linha2 = individualDep.get(father);  
    depenFather= linha2.split(" "); 
    String linha3 = individualHour.get(father);
    hourFather = linha3.split(" ");

    String linhaA = individualID.get(mother);       
    idMother = linha1.split(" ");
    String linhaB = individualDep.get(mother);  
    depenMother= linha2.split(" "); 
    String linhaC = individualHour.get(mother);
    hourMother = linha3.split(" ");

    String [] idChild = new String [idFather.length];
    int crossPoint = (int) (Math.random()*idFather.length);

    for(int i=0; i<idFather.length; i++)
    {
        if (i<crossPoint)
            idChild[i] = idFather[i];
        else
            idChild [i] = idMother[i];
    }

    System.out.println("child" + idChild.toString());
    return idChild;     
}
```

Comment: You have to `override` the `toString()` method if you want behavior different than standard.  Calling `idChild.toString()` is just giving you the object type and location as a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through all childs in your array, then you need to loop through it, other wise you are attempting to read an array of objects as a string!

Try:

```
foreach (string s in idChild)
    {
         System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way `toString()` works (documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--)): the default implementation of the `Object` class (and of all arrays) shows the class name, the `@` symbol and the hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

The documentation says:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object.

So it's really up to the programmer to choose what "textually represents" means.

If you want to print the `String` representation of all the items in an array you have to iterate over it.